# Why casting a quoted string to "string &" causes a crash?

Tags: c++

*Please note that's just a curious question, I don't need a problem solution!*

I have a method that takes in a string reference `(string &some_string)` and only reads from referenced string. Writing some code I forgot that it needs a reference and passed a quoted string (not a variable, just like "something") and IDE suggested casting it to string reference, as it won't compile. I didn't give it a thought and applied the suggestion (now passing `(string &) "something"`). And my program crashed as it reached this piece of code. So, why exactly would it cause a crash, compiling without even a warning (g++, c++11)? I don't really understand it since I'm only reading from this string.

Example:

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>


using namespace std;

class CharSet
{
private:
    const string basis = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ";
    const int N = 26;
    string array;  // string containing all element of the set
    int length;


    bool add_element(char chr) // Add an element (as char) if not already. Returns true if added, false if not.
    {
        bool b = false;
        if (!in_set(chr) && basis.find(chr) != string::npos) {
            array += chr;
            length++;
            b = true;
        }
        return b;
    }

    bool in_set(char chr) const  // Checks whether an element (as char) is in set. Returns corresponding bool value.
    {
        bool b = false;
        if (array.find(chr) != string::npos) b = true;
        return b;
    }
public:
    explicit CharSet(string& str)  // str - string of possible elements
    {
        array = "";
        length = 0;
        int len = (int) str.length();
        for (int i = 0; i < len; i++)
            add_element(str[i]);
        if (str.length() != length)
            cout << "\nSome mistakes corrected. Elements read: " << array << endl;
    }
};

int main()
{
    CharSet A((string &)"AKEPTYUMRX");
    getchar();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `"a string literal"` is not a `std::string`, but a `const char[N]`.  Treating objects as something they are not is something that is likely to cause a crash.

Comment: @NathanOliver casting doesn't solve this problem?

Comment: Nope, it is the cause of the problem.

Comment: @NathanOliver Casting a string literal to `std::string` should work due to the corresponding non-explicit converting constructor, right? Does casting to `std::string&` cause the problem by itself?

Comment: @NathanOliver I still surprised this completely tricked both compiler and IDE (CLion's got pretty smart assistance) while it's not something like messing with dynamic memory

Comment: Casting it to `std::string` creates a temporary. [Temporaries cannot bind to non-const lvalue references](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1565600/how-come-a-non-const-reference-cannot-bind-to-a-temporary-object). If your method doesn't attempt to mutate `some_string`, you can make it take a `const string &` instead of a `string &`. If it _does_, are you sure you should be calling it on a temporary?

Comment: @DanielLangr Casting it to a `std::string` would be fine, it will create a new string object initialized with the string literal contents.  Casting to a `string&` just treats the `const char[N]` as is it was a `std::string`, which will cause all sorts of issues.

Comment: I'd really like to see a [mcve].

Comment: And an indication why c-style casts are dangerous.

Comment: @GaussGun Doing `(string &) "something"` basically tells the compiler: Look, I know what I'm doing so just do that cast and let me get on with the code.  Had you tried the C++ way and used `static_cast<string&>("string literal")`, you would have received a nice compiler error.

Comment: @NathanOliver I guess that answers my question completely. Why don't you make it into an answer?

Comment: @FredLarson if you still need it, here it is. Could accidentally remove something while simplifying but should work.

Comment: I'm with @CaptainGiraffe This is why C-sty;le casts are a bad idea in C++ code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A cast like this

```
(string)"a string literal"
```

constructs a new `std::string` by passing `"a string literal"` as an argument to its constructor. It is equivalent to `static_cast<std::string>("a string literal")`. It is completely valid, even though C-style casts in C++ are a bad idea in general.

On the other hand, a cast like this

```
(string&)"a string literal"
```

constructs a reference to an `std::string` object that resides at the same location as the string literal. Since there is no such object at that location, using this reference results in undefined behaviour (often expressed as a crash). This cast is equivalent to `reinterpret_cast<std::string&>("a string literal")`. You might know that `reinterpret_cast` is dangerous and should be avoided as much as possible. With `reinterpret_cast`, the compiler trusts the programmer nearly totally, which is not really a wise thing to do, but such is the C++ way.

For your function to be able to accept a string literal, it should have a `const std::string&` parameter, or perhaps better, if you are using C++17, an `std::string_view`.

Comment: Cases when it behaves as intended (if you pass a short enough string) are just a part of undefined behaviour, right?

Comment: I guess they might be, although given common implementations of std::string, I don't really see how it could happen. But in theory everything is possible.